# Book of Revelation overview in Catholic Church

Tags: revelation, catholic-bible

What does the Catholic Church believe about prophesy in the Book of Revelation? Does that mention the Second Coming of Christ? Can you give me a brief overview of the subject in Roman Catholic belief?

Comment: Welcome to C.SE.  Yes, the Catholic Church believes in the second coming of Christ.  Your question is too generic; what is it about prophecy / second coming that you are interested in?

Comment: There is quite a lot the RCC teaches about end-time ideas, so if that is what you are interested in, answers can be provided based on the catechism. But as GratefulDisciple says, it helps if you are clear about what you would like to know

Comment: It's good to have you on the site, Amal. This question is vast because nearly all of the 21 chapters in the book of Revelation are prophetic! In a Catholic Encyclopedia I have, it has 20 pages under the heading 'Revelation'. If I see anything specific about the Book of Revelation, I will form answer. For sure, though, Catholicism believes in the second coming of Christ.

Comment: I read Book of Revelation, but it's a little bit hard to grasp. I was wandering does the new earth in  chapter 21 represent afterlife in second coming